# period in string doesn't get replaced

Tags: javascript

I have a string "messages.get.342" that I want to convert to "messages/get/342". Unfortunately, when I call `"messages.get.342".replace('.', '/')`, I get `"messages/get.342"`. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a global replace with regex like this.

```
"messages.get.342".replace(/\./g, '/');
```

**Edit:**

You can also do it like this; it is a little longer but can be less confusing.

```
var myString = "messages/get/342";
var regex = new RegExp(/\./, "g");
myString = mystring.replace(regex, myString);
```

You have the following three options available to you with the javascript regex object:

1. **i** - case insensitive matching
2. **g** - global matching
3. **m** - multiline matching

You can use the other two options in replace of the g **(/i or "i")** or in combination with the g **(/gi or "gi")**.

Answer (score 1):

Use Regular Expression

```
 "messages.get.342".replace(/\./g, '/')
```

Comment: that worked. i'll +1 if you explain why it works in your answer

Comment: `replace` function accepts regular expression as pattern to match. In Regular Expression `g` is for global. So it replaces all instances of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a regular expression with the global flag to replace ALL instances of the period:

```
document.write("messages.get.342".replace(/\./g, '/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it globally:

```
"messages.get.342".replace(/\./g, '/')
```

The `\.` is an escaped period, and the slashes around it indicate a pattern match. You have to escape a literal period if you're doing a pattern match. The g means global, i.e., match and replace all occurrences, not just the first.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `replace` for strings. `"messages.get.342".split('.').join('/')` is recommended.

Comment: Umm, I just saw it in lots of examples on the web. I now found a discussion at [JavaScript’s Dream Team: in praise of split and join](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/javascripts-dream-team-in-praise-of-split-and-join/); it turns out that the split/join method usually is slower. But still, you don't have to trouble around with String->RegExp escaping.